# Why do library designers use ByteString where Text seems to be appropriate?

Tags: haskell, attoparsec, aeson

Working on my app I've stumbled into a problem of [Aeson not decoding UTF8 input](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/105). Digging deeper I found out that it relies on [`Parser ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.10.1.1/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#t%3aParser) of Attoparsec, which seems to be the source of the problem to me. But it's actually not what I'm asking here about.

The thing is it's not the only place I've seen people using `ByteString` where, as it seems obvious to me, only `Text` is appropriate, because JSON is not some binary file, it is a readable text and it may very well contain UTF8 characters.

So I am wondering whether I'm missing something and there are valid reasons to choose `ByteString` over `Text` or it is simply a widespread phenomenon of a bad library design caused by majority of people caring less about any other character sets than latin.

Comment: Note that ByteString precedes Text by quite a few years. No doubt there are a good number of libraries that chose to use ByteString when Text wasn't an option, so it is mistaken to cite them as "bad library design".

Comment: @stephentetley I don't understand what you found offensive about those words and the downvote. Anyway I wasn't trying to critisize, but just trying to clear things out. Your remark on the probable historical reasons is helpful.

Comment: When using Text in api design, you have to be certain you can always rely on the input having UTF8 encoding. I can't tell you how many times I've made that assumption, feeling safe and sound, only to have my program crash down the line for valid input (valid semantically in the problem domain) that happened to exhibit some other encoding. If your interface is in Text, then you have no control inside of your program over encoding anymore. I've found that to be needlessly restrictive in most designs (although admittedly not ALL of them).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think [your problem](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/105) is just a misunderstanding.

```
Prelude> print "Ёжик лижет мёд."
"\1025\1078\1080\1082 \1083\1080\1078\1077\1090 \1084\1105\1076."
Prelude> putStrLn "\1025\1078\1080\1082 \1083\1080\1078\1077\1090 \1084\1105\1076."
Ёжик лижет мёд.
Prelude> "{\"a\": \"Ёжик лижет мёд.\"}"
"{\"a\": \"\1025\1078\1080\1082 \1083\1080\1078\1077\1090 \1084\1105\1076.\"}"
```

When you `print` a value containing a `String`, the `Show` instance for `Char` is used, and that escapes all characters with code points above 127. To get the glyphs you want, you need to `putStr[Ln]` the `String`.

So `aeson` properly decoded the utf8-encoded input, as should be expected because it utf8-encodes the values itself:

```
encode = {-# SCC "encode" #-} encodeUtf8 . toLazyText . fromValue .
         {-# SCC "toJSON" #-} toJSON
```

So to the question why `aeson` uses `ByteString` and not `Text` for the final target of encoding and starting point of decoding.

Because that is the appropriate type. The encoded values are intended to be transferred portably between machines. That happens as a stream of bytes (octets, if we're in pedantic mood). That is exactly what a `ByteString` provides, a sequence of bytes that then have to be treated in an application-specific way. For the purposes of `aeson`, the stream of bytes shall be encoded in utf-8, and `aeson` assumes the input of the `decode` function is valid utf-8, and encodes its output as valid utf-8.

Transferring e.g. `Text` would run into portability problems, since a 16-bit encoding depends on endianness, so `Text` is not an appropriate format for interchange of data between machines. Note that `aeson` uses `Text` as an intermediate type when encoding (and presumably also when decoding), because that is an appropriate type to use at intermediate stages.

Comment: This makes a whole lot of sense. Thank you! So it looks like I made a false alarm there on the issue tracker.

Comment: I don't see why it's a parser/emitter's responsibility to pick a format for /my/ network transfers.  It is parsing textual data, and Data.Text has functions for making and taking in any of UTF encodings, whereas Aeson is limited to parsing UTF8 encoded bytestrings.